# How do I select OS for CircleCI build?

Tags: circleci

I would like to build my project on a MacOS machine, unlike travis that simply has an "OS" field, or jenkins that allows you to set labels on slaves, I don't see anything like that here.

Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to get a build running on OSX with Circle? The docs should help you get started: https://circleci.com/docs/ios-builds-on-os-x/

If that didn't work, perhaps you could share more details about your configuration?

Comment: I'm not building an iOS project, I am building a CLI tool that has Mac specific libs defined by Omnibus.